# Problems in creating dummy variables

Tags: stata, dummy-variable

The treatment boroughs are five boroughs with ID 1, 2, 3, 6, 14. The “Operation Theseus" policy lasts from week 80 to week 85.

`ocu`: borough ID

I tried creating dummies of `treated` and `time` but they just show as zero for all

```
gen treated =0 if missing(ocu)==0
replace treated =1 if ocu==1/2/3/6/14
gen time = (week==80-85) & !missing(week)`
```

Comment: The jargon of DID is likely to make sense only to economists.

Answer (score 1):

`ocu == 1/2/3/6/14` is a legal expression, but is likely to be a long way from what you want.

```
occ == 1 | occ == 2 | occ == 3 | occ == 6 | occ == 14
```

is legal and long-winded and

```
inlist(occ, 1, 2, 3, 6, 14)
```

legal and likely to be appealing as an expression for: does `occ` take on any the values specified?

Although Stata supports `|` as an "or" operator (and not `/` for that purpose) note that

```
occ == 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 | 14
```

is legal but almost never what anyone would want, as it is parsed

```
(occ == 1) | 2 | 3 | 6 | 14
```

and will always be evaluated 1 (true), regardless of the value of `occ`, as just one of the other arguments 2 3 6 14 being non-zero means that the entire expression evaluates to 1 (true).

The expression `week==80-85` is also incorrect syntax if you want it to mean `week` between 80 and 85. Stata will evaluate `week == 80-85`, applying the subtraction first and so test for equality with -5. See precedence rules as documented in `help operators`.

*The order of evaluation (from first to last) of all operators is ! (or ~), ^, - (negation), /, *, - (subtraction), +, != (or ~=), >, <, <=, >=, ==, &, and |.**

Subtraction comes before testing for equality.

You may want `week >= 80 & week <= 85` or `inrange(week, 80, 85)`.

If `week` is between 80 and 85, then it can't be missing. That test is redundant (but harmless).

Comment: Thanks for the help!
The difference-in-differences strategy requires common trend assumptions. Please draw two figures about trends of police hours per 1000 population and crime per 1000 population from 2004 to 2005.
what should be the code for this one?

Comment: Please post a new question explaining your data and your code so far.